# Twisting Solid Steel Bar - Annealed, Hardened or Doesn't mater?

Tags: elasticity, structural-beam

Workshop project underway...

Been decades since I was in a physics class.

Building something out of steel - options are mild steel 1018 and alloy steel 4140 that can be hardened by heat treatment.

Here's the situation:

50 inch bar 1 inch wide and 2 inches tall - 50 inches long.

Fixed both ends and a twist in the center.

I have 1018 and 4140 at my disposal.

I have maxed out the dimensions - can't get any bigger.

I want the stiffest setup - most resistance to twist.

After some research on both mild steel 1018 and hardened 4140 alloy steel both steels will twist the same amount since their Young's modulus and Poisson ratios are the same - thus their shear modulus are the same.

https://www.makeitfrom.com/compare/Quenched-and-Tempered-4140-Cr-Mo-Steel/SAE-AISI-1018-G10180-Carbon-Steel

Is this correct?

Does the type of steel even matter in this case?

Will both steels twist the same amount if the dimensions are the same?

I am talking about stiffness in the elastic range of the material - if I have permanent deformation occurring than obviously steel is not the right choice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The elastic properties of metals depend strongly on their composition and very little on slight additives and treatment history (the latter play their part in modulating the plasticity properties, such as strength). The reason is that the stiffness depends on the curvature of the [pair potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interatomic_potential) between adjacent atoms. All steels, being mostly iron, have nearly the same elastic moduli as iron, sharing a Young's modulus of around 200 GPa and a shear modulus of around 80 GPa, for instance.

Stress-strain diagrams such as the following drive the point home; note that the initial slope - the elastic region - is identical even when a steel is processed to have a very different strength.

[image]